# How do I use __str__() and __repr__() for a singly linked list in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

everyone. I've got a bit of a problem I need to sort out, and I was hoping for some assistance on what to do. So, I have this Python 3.6 assignment I've been working on, regarding Singly Linked Lists. Most of my test cases for appending/prepending, removing from front and back, and deleting nodes altogether are going well so far. However, I have some issues with a few of my test cases. The issues revolve around my use of the `__str__(self)` and `__repr__(self)` functions.

Down below is the code I'm providing. (EDIT: I left only the test codes that has the faults that need fixing. All the other test cases are fine):

```
class LinkedList(object):
    class Node(object):
        # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        ''' no need for get or set, we only access the values inside the
        LinkedList class. and really: never have setters. '''

        def __init__(self, value, next = None):
            self.value = value
            self.next = next

        def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self.value)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.value) + "; "

    def __init__(self, initial=None):
        self.front = self.back = self.current = None

    def empty(self):
        return self.front == self.back == None

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.front
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        string = 'List[ '
        curr_node = self.front

        while curr_node != None:
            string += str(curr_node)
            curr_node = curr_node.next()
        string += ']'

        return string

    def __repr__(self):
        nodes = []
        curr = self.front

        while curr:
            nodes.append(repr(curr))
            curr = curr.next
        return '[' +', '.join(nodes) + ']'

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current:
            tmp = self.current.value
            self.current = self.current.next
            return tmp
        else:
            raise StopIteration()

    def push_front(self, value):
        x = self.Node(value, self.front)

        if self.empty():
            self.front = self.back = x
        else:
            self.front = x

#you need to(at least) implement the following three methods

    def pop_front(self):      
        if self.empty():
            raise RuntimeError("Empty List")
        x = self.front.value
        self.front = self.front.next
        if not self.front:
            self.back = None
        return x

    def push_back(self, value):
        if self.empty():
            self.front = self.back = self.Node(value, None)
        else:
            x = self.Node(value, None)
            self.back.next = x
            self.back = x

    def pop_back(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise RuntimeError("Empty List")
        y = self.back.value
        if not self.front.next:
            self.front = self.back = None
        else:
            x = self.front
            while x.next is not self.back:
                x = x.next
            x.next = None
            self.back = x
        return y

class TestInitialization(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        linked_list = LinkedList(("one", 2, 3.141592))
        self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), "one")
        self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), 2)
        self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), 3.141592)

class TestStr(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        linked_list = LinkedList((1, 2, 3))
        self.assertEqual(linked_list.__str__(), '1, 2, 3')

class TestRepr(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        linked_list = LinkedList((1, 2, 3))
        self.assertEqual(linked_list.__repr__(), 'LinkedList((1, 2, 3))')


if '__main__' == __name__:
    unittest.main()
```

Now, with the code out of the way, I'm going to provide the problems I'm getting in the console:

```
1) Error at TestInitialization. RuntimeError("Empty List")
2) Failure at TestRepr. AssertionError: '[]' != 'LinkedList((1, 2, 3))'
- []
+ LinkedList((1, 2, 3))
3) Failure at TestStr. AssertionError: 'List[ ]' != '1, 2, 3'
- List[ ]
+ 1, 2, 3
```

I hate to be a bother, but I'd like to ask for any advice or hints to help me correct my two failures and prevent the one error. So, is there any way I can use to try and do so? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Please do not just dump your whole code here.

Comment: I think we don't need to see the test cases that already pass.

Comment: Without diving in to the code dump too far, it looks like the `__str__()` and `__repr__()` methods you defined should only give output like that when called on an empty linked list. The line `self.front = self.back = self.current = None` looks problematic.

Comment: As a start, in the constructor for `LinkedList` you don't appear to be using the `initial` argument.

Comment: My apologies about that. I removed the passing test cases, and kept the ones that have errors. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: @HansMusgrave What would you suggest I do about that? I'm not using the initial argument in the Linked List constructor, which is strange of my instructor to give us, but I'm curious as to how I should use it.

Is it possible to just change the contents of that constructor to become `self.front = self.back = self.current = initial` to amount to the same thing?

Comment: @cdarke I was wondering about that. I could use it to replace the None variable in `self.front = self.back = self.current = None` so that it isn't wasted.

Comment: @Deyeaz That probably isn't what you want. If you set all those to `initial`, then in your test case the value of that node becomes the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`. You probably want three different nodes corresponding to each of those values, and your `__init__()` should reflect that. If this is a school assignment, talking to your peers and professor is going to be the most beneficial use of your time after you've done all you can do on your own.

Comment: are the test cases written by yourself or given as "fix it until it works like this"?

Comment: @PatrickArtner The latter. They were provided by the instructor, along with the base code. The only bits I wrote by myself were pop_front, push_back, and pop_back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `TestInitialization` work, your init function hat to provide a linkage of

```
3.141592 -> 2 -> "one"
```

if init(...)ed with `("one", 2, 3.141592)` - you can see that by inspecting the testcase, it pops from back and you need to match the values provided. 
You can solve it by pushing each one onto the front in init:

```
def __init__(self, initial=None):
    self.front = self.back = self.current = None
    for i in initial:
        self.push_front(i)  

# I find this counterintuitive, blame your teacher.
```

To make `TestStr` work, you init it with `(1,2,3)` and have to provide an output of `'(1,2,3)'` - due to the way `__init__` now works you need to collect all nodes into a list, and return it reverse-joined (or go from back to front through list):

```
def __str__(self):
    elem = []
    curr_node = self.front

    while curr_node != None:
        elem.append(str(curr_node.value)) # collect node values, not the "7; " str  
        curr_node = curr_node.next()
    # join reversed list 
    return ', '.join(elem[::-1]) # need to reverse the list due to how __init__ works
```

To make `TestRepr` work, you need the `__str__` output and prefix/postfix it with `'LinkedList(('` and `'))'`

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'LinkedList(('+ str(self) + '))'
```

I can't test myself, as `NameError: name 'unittest' is not defined`.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to include: 
`from __future__ import print_function`
`import unittest` at the start of my program. Sorry about that! But thank you! This is really a step in the right direction! Is this all within the Node class or the Linked List class, by the by?

Comment: @Deyeaz If you need to ask if its Node or LinkedList .. maybe you should go to your peers and ask your teacher. The testcases are for LinkedLists - so any code modification should go into LinkedList as well ... - after looking at your Node's ` __str__()`  I had to modiefiy the code - the Node.str() adds `'; '` to each elem which we do not want here...

Comment: Right. Thank you again for all your help! I appreciate your efforts, and will do well to learn from them!